# Create environment in postman using postman API

Tags: json, postman

I'm trying to create an environment file in Postman using the Postman API by referring to their [API documentation](https://docs.api.getpostman.com/?_ga=2.67436689.1486695132.1524501201-236906680.1523908849#152d94ab-a94d-f5fc-c8db-73c61a56f4ce)

POST route - `https://api.getpostman.com/environments`

Request Headers - `Content-type and API key`

Request Body -

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "environment": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "maxLength": 254,
                    "minLength": 1
                },
                "values": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "maxItems": 100,
                    "additionalItems": false,
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "key": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "maxLength": 254
                                "minLength": 1
                            },
                            "value": { "type": "string" },
                            "enabled": { "type": "boolean" }
                        },
                        "required": ["key", "value"]
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": ["name"]
        }
    },
    "required": ["environment"]
}
```

But the response is returning this message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "malformedRequestError",
        "message": "Missing required property: environment"
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the other sample body on the API docs and edit the details, this should work for you. The example you used is just telling you the schema information from what I can see.

```
{
    "environment": {
        "name": "My New Environment",
        "values": [
            {"key": "variable_name_1", "value": "my_value"},
            {"key": "variable_name_2", "value": "my_other_value"}
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Danny, I'm able to create the environment but it's not showing up in my environment list on top right corner.

Comment: Are you using the native app but creating environments through an API call? Also it might not be synced so you probably won’t see them yet. If that’s another issue, you might want to raise another question. Seems like the original one is answered if you can create the environment. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the native app but creating env using API to eliminate any manual step to create the environment. It says its all synced up and `https://api.getpostman.com/environments` has my new env

Comment: I’ve come away from my machine now so I couldn’t tell you just yet. Have you tried the classic steps of closing the app / logging in and out etc. :(

Comment: Yes, I've done the IT black magic of restarting/logging out/in etc. but no luck

Comment: created a new topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50008359/newly-created-environment-not-showing-up-on-postman-native-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.token);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes