# Newly created environment not showing up on postman native app

Tags: postman

I'm using postman native app but creating the environment using the postman API to avoid a manual step. I was successfully able to create the environment using the following:

POST - https://api.getpostman.com/environments

```
{
    "environment": {
        "name": "My New Environment",
        "values": [
            {"key": "variable_name_1", "value": "my_value"},
            {"key": "variable_name_2", "value": "my_other_value"}
        ]
    }
}
```

But, the newly created environment is not being displayed in the native app's environment's dropdown (even after the sync is complete).

Did anyone experience a similar issue and any pointers on how to resolve it ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing the ones I create from the API call, in my dropdown on the client app UI. It's only seen one workspace though, don't know if that's a thing for you. You could try a manual re-sync of the data? Settings > Sync > Re-sync

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried adding the environment using the same call and I noticed one thing - the environment is created in ANOTHER workspace than the one I was sending the request from. Looks like a bug in Postman. Try double checking into ALL of your workspaces , clicking on "Sync" button again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case, I had two tabs of the same env opened. So one was conflicting with another. When I closed all tabs and open only one everything worked.